# Multi level expander WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, expander

I have below data structure

```
public class enrichment
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Pages
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<enrichment> enrichment { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class SubChapter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Pages> pages { get; set; }
    public string parentId { get; set; }
}

public class Chapter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Pages> pages { get; set; }
    public List<SubChapter> chapters { get; set; }
}
public class TOCData
{
    public List<Chapter> chapters { get; set; }
}
```

And sample data looks like  this

```
Chapter 1
  page 1
  page 2
  Chapter 1.1 
      page a
      page b          
Chapter 2 
   page 3
Chapter 3 
   chapter 3.1
      page c
      page d
```

I want to present this data in an expander control and i been able to did it for 2 levels using the structure explained here http://pastebin.com/W8Nx857K
But i cant repeat it to next level ( ie when a chapter contain sub chapter ) How can i represent it on my expander.
What i did was Chapter - bind Pages in an expander. My question is how to add Chapters as well. Whether can i bind it simply or do i need to create controls manually 
Is any examples or modifications to code suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can either use a TreeView with a customized Template containing expander. Should take 1/2 hour or if your structure is really strict you create 2 Controls (ChapterViewer and PageViewer and derive both from ItemsControl. Their DataContext will be your corresponding classes. Then you can define DataTemplates for them, meaning a Chapter will be visually represented by a ChapterViewer and a Page by a PageViewer. This allows you to build up your structure the way you want. But it's a little fixed in structure. I would go with the templated TreeView.

EDIT---->
This is code from the sample I created (http://1drv.ms/Tdq2Re):

ViewModel.cs (basic data structure):

```
public ViewModel()
        {
            this.TocData = new TOCData
            {
                Name = "Chapters",
                Chapters = new ObservableCollection<Chapter>
                {
                    new Chapter{ Name="Chapter 1", 
                        Elements = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>
                        {
                            new Chapter
                            {
                                Name = "Introduction", 
                                Elements = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>
                                {
                                    new Page(){Label = "Page I"},
                                    new Page(){Label = "Page II"},
                                    new Page(){Label = "Page III"}
                                }
                            },
                            new Page(){Label = "Page 1"},
                            new Page(){Label = "Page 2"},
                            new Page(){Label = "Page 3"},
                            new Page(){Label = "Page 4"},
                        }},            
                    new Chapter{ Name="Chapter 2", Elements = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>
                        {              
                            new Page(){Label = "Page 5"},
                            new Page(){Label = "Page 6"},
                            new Page(){Label = "Page 7"},
                            new Page(){Label = "Page 8"},
                        }},
                }
            };
        }
```

It is used like that:

```
<Grid>
   <local:ChapterControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TocData.Chapters}"  />
</Grid>
```

The ChapterControl.xaml.cs (CustomControl):

```
 public class ChapterControl : ItemsControl
    {
        static ChapterControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ChapterControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ChapterControl)));
        }
    }
```

And the Styles, etc. for the control:

```
<!-- Chapter Template -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ChapterTemplate"  DataType="local:Chapter">
        <StackPanel>
            <local:ChapterControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- Page Template -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pageTemplate"  DataType="local:Page">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" Margin="25,0,0,0" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ChapterItemStyleSelector x:Key="chapterItemStyleSelector" PageTemplate="{StaticResource pageTemplate}" ChapterTemplate="{StaticResource ChapterTemplate}" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ChapterControl}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource chapterItemStyleSelector}" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ChapterControl}">
                    <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I tried few options, but not yet reproduced the needed one. I tried Hierarchical Tempalte and been able to render till 2 levels.Can you post some sample as per your suggestions?

Comment: Ok, I built you a sample showing what you want (I guess): http://1drv.ms/Tdq2Re

The basic idea is to use an ItemsControl and decide for each child wheter you need another ExpanderElement going deeper or just a TextBlock / Whatever (Page) by using a DataTemplateSelector. Its too much code to post here though. I will try to insert the main points into the answer. It's a pretty rough sketch though...

Comment: Yes it did implemented it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is get rid of `SubChapter` and change Chapter's list to `List<Chapter>`.

Then create a UserControl for Chapter that contains an Expander, a ListBox for pages and a ListBox for Chapters.

This way your hierarchy should work without any problem .

Comment: But cant avoid Subchapters fully. Since Chapter and SubChapters have different properties .Also Chapter contains a List Of SubChapters as well

Comment: Well, you should avoid your SubChapters fully because the only difference between them and "Normal" Chapter is that they know their parentID. Add parentID to Chapter, this way you can remove SubChapter completely and use only Chapter. This is way better as they function completely the same therefore easier code management for you & you'll be able to add more levels of "SubChapter" without breaking sweat

Comment: The source of data structure is different . I am parsing the data in json format to C# objects. Thats the limitation i am saying that cant remove Subchapters